# Drools Workbench (a.k.a Guvnor) Rule Conflict Validation Issue

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor

I am trying to figure out why Drools keep saying the rules are in conflict for this guided decision table. I also created this table in an Excel sheet and imported into Drools and it gives me no conflicts for the same exact set of rules.

Rule that conflicts: (the only thing different in each rule is the start and end distance range including the AwardCost.

```
rule "Row 1 DistanceAwardTable" 
  dialect "mvel" 
when 
  $distanceAwardRequest: DistanceAwardRequest(startDistanceRange >= 0,
                                              endDistanceRange <= 1000 ) 
then 
  AwardResult $awardResult = new AwardResult(); 
  $awardResult.setAirlineId( 1 ); 
  $awardResult.setAwardCost( 15000 ); 
  insert( $awardResult ); 
end
```

Same Rule that doesn't give me a conflict error:

```
rule "Row 1" 
  dialect "mvel" 
when 
  DistanceAwardRequest(startDistanceRange >= 0,
                       endDistanceRange <= 1000) 
then 
  AwardResult $awardResult = new AwardResult(); 
  $awardResult.setAwardCost(15000); 
  $awardResult.setAirlineId(1); 
  insert( $awardResult );
end
```

The only two things different here is that in one set of rules the DistanceAwardRequest is bound to $distanceAwardRequest and in the other rule this isn't.

I've also created a test to see if more than one rule fires and it does not.

What am I missing here?

***UPDATE

Example decision table:

Airline ID: 1
Start Distance = 0
End Distance = 1000
Cost: 50000
Class: 1

Airline ID: 1
Start Distance: 1001
End Distance = 2000
Cost: 60000
Class: 1

Airline ID: 1
Start Distance: 2001
End Distance: 3000
Cost: 70000
Class 1

Comment: One rule with one constraint each for a couple of attributes can't be in conflict with itself. Therefore, showing just one rule is pointless. What is the exact error message and which rules were given in the error mesage? - It is of course also possible that this is a bug in the validation code.

Comment: What you are missing is the entire set of values you are using in your decision table to identify whether this is a bug in the validation code or not.

Comment: Let me post the decision table example here above

Comment: @EstebanAliverti See the example above of what the table looks like. The criteria is if the distance is between the Start Distance and the End Distance with X class then the cost is X. Airline is not used as criteria in the table, but is returned as part of the action.

Comment: I think that this could be a confusion/bug in Drools because of the way you are defining your ranges. Usually, you use a single attribute of a class and set the range in your rules. Something like `DistanceAwardRequest(range >=0, range <=1000)`. This is obviously not your case. What is the validation error message you are getting?